# How to assign UIGestureRecognizerDelegate to CKComponentController

Tags: ios, objective-c, componentkit

I use the next code to setup UIPanGestureRecognizer in my component:

```
MyComponent *c =[super newWithView:{
  [UIView class],
  {
    {
      CKComponentGestureAttribute(
      [UIPanGestureRecognizer class],
      &setupPanRecognizer,
      @selector(panGesture:context:),
      {}
      )
    },
    {
      @selector(setUserInteractionEnabled:), @YES
    }
  }
  }
  component: [MyOtherComponent newOtherComponentWithMode:model context:context]];
```

I process `panGesture:context` in MyComponentController object.

My problem is that `UIPanGestureRecognizer` blocks feed view from scrolling. In order to fix this I want to use `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol and allow both (scroll view and my pan) recognizers to work simultaneously.

My question is how can I assign my component controller as a delegate for `UIPanGestureRecognizer`? `setupPanRecognizer` is just a `C function` and it does not have reference to `MyComponentController` object or even the component itself.

The only way I see now is to get list of gesture recognisers somewhere in `didUpdateComponent` method in my controller, find the right one and assign delegate there. 
Does ComponentKit provide any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

```
CKComponentViewAttributeValue CKComponentGestureAttribute(Class gestureRecognizerClass,
                                                      CKComponentGestureRecognizerSetupFunction setupFunction,
                                                      CKComponentAction action,
                                                      CKComponentForwardedSelectors delegateSelectors)
```

You can find the "delegateSelectors" argument at last, so you could try to pass in a vector of selectors which you would like to response in the controller.